# In Netbeans, is there a way to show all public variables and methods within a class without actually generating the interface file?

Tags: java, xcode, netbeans, interface

In Xcode, there is a function where if I want to see the part of my class that is accessible to the public, I would simply press a button named "generate interface" and it will show a screen that only contain variable names and method names that are declared public without actually create a new file containing those variables and methods.

I was just wondering if there is a similar function in NetBeans for Java class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Navigator window that displays all the class variables. You can use filters to display only what you want.

Check the following link: [Navigator](https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/code_navigator/Navigator%20spec.html)